# Firebase - Child dentro de outro child

Tags: android, firebase

Gostaria de saber como posso colocar um child dentro de outro child no firebase, por exemplo, criar um child que chame "Empresa" e dentro desse child colocar outros childs com cada sede dentro, não sei se fui claro, me ajudem por favor.
PS: Estou usando android studio.
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `ref.child()` em um child inexistente e dar um `ref.push()` para criar.
Então é só fazer:

```
DatabaseReference empresaRef = ref.child("Empresa");
```

Para acessar as sedes:

```
DatabaseReference sedeRef = empresaRef.child("Sede");
```

E para criar uma nova é só:

```
Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
Sede sede = new Sede();
DatabaseReference empresaRef = 
ref.child("Empresa").push().setValue(empresa);
DatabaseReference sedeRef = empresaRef.child("Sede").push().setValue(sede);
```

Porém é recomendado que se salve usando um ID única ao invés do nome.
Para gerar a ID use:

```
Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
Sede sede = new Sede();

String empresaID = ref.push().getKey();
DatabaseReference empresaRef = ref.child(empresaID);
empresaRef.setValue(empresa);

String sedeID = empresaRef.push().getKey();
DatabaseReference sedeRef = empresaRef.child(sedeID);
sedeRef.setValue(sede);
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você tem que setar os valores que precisa, começando pela sua root, depois da root você passa pelo nódo pai e do pai você cria seu filho desejado.

Exemplo:

```
Firebase newRef = ref.child("root").child("empresa").child("sede").push();
newRef.setValue("DollOnWorld");
```